# Why Does Vista List All BUT My Recently Used Applications?

Tags: windows-vista, start-menu

I click the start button, then choose "programs" - and Vista lists me all my application shortcuts.. except for the ones I've used recently. I have to click the two down arrows to list my recently-used applications.

This seems retarded. Why would Microsoft want to show me all my unused applications and hide my recently used applications?

Comment: The Programs menu is not a list of recently used programs. The recent list (MRU) is on the top of the start menu, on the left (if enabled) and appears to use frequency statistics to determine what you are more likely to want, instead of just looking at the order you have used them in. I think this is what you are referring to, but I can't be sure from the question.

Comment: Start -> Programs... look at all the programs you can start! Wait.. all the programs I've used recently are hidden, I have to press the double down arrive on that menu to reveal them! Retarded!

Comment: You must be new to Windows, its always been retarded.

Answer (score 1):

Every time Microsoft has its millions of users trained to do something a certain way they go and change the process.  If you ask me, someone there has a sick sense of humor, and this is how he gets his kicks.

Comment: Any programmer worth their salt would shun Microsoft - and it shows. Their juniors who don't understand Microsoft's predatory history also don't understand users and user interfaces. They don't respect history. If they did they wouldn't work at Microsoft.